# Compare std_logic_vector in a if() condition vhdl

Tags: if-statement, hex, vhdl, intel-fpga

I am trying to compare counting value (std_logic_vector) with a defined hex value. but i dont get the result the way i did as below

```
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(res_bits-1 DOWNTO 0):= x"0000"; --res_bits =16
signal round : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(res_bits-1 DOWNTO 0):= x"0000";
signal cnt : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(res_bits-1 DOWNTO 0):= x"0000"; --res_bits =16
    process(clk_50)
begin
    if (falling_edge(clk_50)) then
        t(1)<=t(0); 
        t(0)<=A;
        t(3)<=t(2); 
        t(2)<=B;
        case (temp) is
            when "0001" => cnt<= cnt + '1';
            when "0010" => cnt<= cnt - '1';
            when "1000" => cnt<= cnt + '1';     
            when "1011" => cnt<= cnt - '1';

        end case;
        count <= cnt;
        if (count = x"0320") then --if count 800
            round <= round + '1';
            cnt <= x"0000";   -- reset cnt
            count <= x"0000";   -- reset count
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Please, edit your question so that it has [mcve] and provide better explanation of the problem.

Comment: You do realise that the equality operator on std_logic_vectors of different sizes is defined to always return false, right?

Comment: No you have not added the rest of the code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're asking anyone who can help you to hit a moving target trickling more information incrementally. Get rid of count, use cnt and compare to 799.

Comment: I've rolled-back your latest edit. Please don't make large edits in the code a few weeks after you asked the initial question. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) what you can and cannot do. If you still have a question for a new piece of code, ask a new question.

Comment: Can you please explain your latest edit??? It does not add any value to the question... Why did you go through the effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: What do you think a std_logic_vector is? `std_logic_vector` is an array of `std_logic`. `std_logic` is an `std_ulogic` which has been resolved. `std_ulogic` is a type that defines states of an electrical line in digital circuits. But more importantly: `std_logic[_vector]` is **not** an integer type.

If you want to do arithmetic with the `+` and `-` operators, you should use an arithmetic type. `signed` and `unsigned`, defined in `numeric_std`, are best suited for this. so don't use `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all`(non standard), but use `use ieee.numeric_std.all` (defined in the standard).

---

Next, some information an resetting a signal. What if you decide to set `res_bits` = 17? Then

```
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(res_bits-1 DOWNTO 0):= x"0000";
```

will not work. So instead use `others` to set all bits to '0' for maximum flexibility. I.e.

```
signal count : UNSIGNED(res_bits-1 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
```

---

Now lets look at the process... Hmmm. There are a number of assignments to `temp`... but you never define `temp`. Cannot help you there...

Then look at the case statements. `case (temp) is...`. I see a when for 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, etc... but what happens when `temp` is e.g. 0? You need to define a `when` for all possibilities. But what if you don't want to do anything for these cases? ... Just do `null`! E.g.

```
case (temp) is
    when "0001" => cnt<= cnt + '1';
    [...]
    when "1110" => cnt<= cnt + '1';
    when others => null; -- <== required
end case;
```

---

Another thing for `case`-statements. Combine situations with the pipe symbol.

```
case (temp) is
    when "0001" | "0111" | "1000" | "1110" => cnt <= cnt + '1';
    when "0010" | "0100" | "1011" | "1101" => cnt <= cnt - '1';
    when others => null;
end case;
```

---

Then about signal assignment. A value applied to a signal will not be applied until the *next* delta cycle. But this delta cycle does not occur until *after* the process is finished. E.g.:

- Imagine `cnt`=799=x"031F" and `temp`="0001" when the process starts.
- at the `case` statement, `cnt <= cnt + 1` is selected. This operation is scheduled for the next delta cycle, nut `cnt` will stay 799 for now.
- So, at `count <= cnt;`, 799 will be scheduled to be assigned to `count`, not 800! But as this operation is also scheduled, `count` will for now still have it's old value (likely 798).
- This means that at `if (count =`, count will still be seen as 798. It will take another two clock cycles for `count` to reach 800, due to the extra registers inferred.

You should probably use variables for temporary values in the process. But watch out with what you are doing: variables loose their value when the process finishes and should never be used outside of the process.

Comment: Naturally, variables in process doesn't loose the value, but do indeed infer a latch if used without assigning a value first, which can be considered harmful.

Comment: "variables loose their value when the process finishes"; You can infer registers using variables, so I wonder if this is what you really meant?